# PHP execute the command "at" to run a SQL query problems

Tags: php, mysql, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have a PHP script that is called from PayPal IPN.  When a user purchases something form my site, the IPN PHP script creates the user in the mysql database.  At a later time, 24hrs, that user needs to be deleted from the database.  I assume that using the "at" command would work.  I believe the problem I am running into is regarding the parentheses in my command.

```
<?php
$email = "buyer@gmail.com";
$cmd = 'mysql -u username -pPassword -e `DELETE FROM db.users WHERE users.email = "$email";`|at tomorrow';
exec($cmd);
?>
```

If I run this page as-is, it throws the following error:

```
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
sh: 1: DELETE: not found
mysql: option '-e' requires an argument
job 38 at Sun Feb  8 04:59:00 2015
```

That is what is leading me to believe there is a problem with my quotes and parentheses.

Comment: Why not use the `mysqli` function set? That's what they're there for

Comment: Because I need it to be scheduled to run at a later date.  Unless you know of a method within the mysql function set that will accomplish that..

Comment: That's what cron jobs are for. Runs at a set time but runs a pure PHP script to access your database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should explain the problem you're running into. The first thing I note is that you use single quotes - those don't interpret the inner string so $email doesn't get replaced for the e-mail value.

Second - you're using backticks. The command gets executed in a bash shell, where the backticks around your query get interpreted as a shell command. Try this:
`$cmd = "echo mysql -u username -pPassword -e \\'DELETE FROM db.users WHERE users.email = \\\"$email\\\"\\' |at tomorrow"`;

Comment: As for using `at` to schedule, I'm not sure that's going to work; it depends on server configuration (especially if you're running on a system you don't administer yourself). Generally such tasks would be solved by adding the tasks to a queue and scheduling a script run (using crontab, for example) which would execute the necessary commands from the queue.

Comment: It is my personal server.  I have used AT many times in the past and it has worked great for me.  I am open to cron jobs if I have a thought...  The problem still is within the $cmd string.  I have my first set of parentheses around the entire command, then another set around the SQL query, then a third around the $email variable.  That doesnt seem to work well..

Comment: You wouldnt happen to know why the sql query is executed immediately and not being passed to the AT command?  I check the database, and the user is deleted immediately.  I check the AT queue, and there is nothing in it.

Comment: You're right, I forgot about that. It's going to execute the first part of the command, generate its output and try to pass that to "at". Try echoing the first part - $cmd = "echo mysql ... "

Comment: 99% there...  So that is echoing the sql query to the AT command, but it is dropping the parentheses around the SQL statement.  Thoughts on that one?

Comment: Yes, escape the apostrophes like this `-e \\'DELETE`.

Comment: Still running into a few problems...   I added the \\'DELETE section, but what exactly do I put at the end of the SQL statement?  I tried users.email = \"$email\";\\' |at tomorrow"   I also tried users.email = \"$email\";'\\ |at tomorrow"   Neither seem to work...

Comment: Typo on my part - there should be no `;` right after the `$email\"`. so you should have `$email\"\\' `

Comment: Good eyes...  Still not executing properly.  When I look at the command that is queued in AT, it shows the SQL query with apostrophes around the query, but not the email address.  It doesnt want to run unless there are quotes around the email.  I tried  WHERE users.email = \\""$email"\\";`|at tomorrow      but that didnt work... Thoughts on that one?

Comment: `\\\"$email\\\"`; those have to be triple-backslashed since one backslash escapes the apostrophe inside PHP, another one is to be displayed in the output and it needs another one to be escaped inside PHP. So the string would end in \\\"$email\\\"\\' | at tomorrow

Comment: Wow, its working...  You taught me quite a bit, and I greatly appreciate your help.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
"mysql -u username -pPassword -e `DELETE FROM db.users WHERE users.email = '$email'`|at tomorrow";
```